# Execute unimportant Javascript files after the page fully loads

Tags: javascript

In my site I have many javascript files, for example:

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script> 
<script src="script3.js"></script> 
<script src="script4.js"></script>
<script src="script5.js"></script>
```

these are slowing my website's load time. so my idea is to load these script files 2 sec after the page fully loads, I am already using defer but I want to load these (script files) in more delay in order to load my pages faster.

Comment: Why so many files? Have you considered combining them all into one or two files?

Comment: yeah, but I add new scripts frequently and as the scripts being cache sometimes the new code doesn't reflect which can create a problem

Comment: [Cache busting](https://curtistimson.co.uk/post/front-end-dev/what-is-cache-busting) will fix that. No need to constantly add new files just because a current file is potentially cached.

Comment: if someone is having slow internet speed then the whole script may not download resulting in some features, not working. Also, if I make a minor change or a major change to the script containing all the JavaScript codes (as told by you) and then 'Cache bust' the whole script file then unnecessarily all the code will be 'cache busted'

Comment: The script isn't executed until it is downloaded entirely - the browser won't execute code that is 'broken' due to it not being fully loaded. Either way the user will need to download all the JS whether it is in one file or spread across 20 files. I did take a look at the scripts on your site and none of them are large (besides jquery). Are you sure it's the scripts slowing down your website's load time?

Comment: according to google page speed insight "Script Evaluation
10,012 ms"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let scriptSources = ['script1.js', 'script2.js', 'script3.js'];

scriptSources.forEach(loadLater)

function loadLater(item, index) {
    
setTimeout(function(){ 

    let script =  document.createElement('script');
    script.src = item;

    document.body.appendChild(script); 
    
    }, 2000 * (index + 1) );
}
```

Comment: if i change the time from 2000ms to 100ms will there be any problem?

Comment: you can play with timing always after , part is timing :)

Comment: I am a little more than a beginner at JavaScript, is it safe to use it on my website?

Comment: you should test anycode in your local machine before deploying to your website. this function will stop after it reads the array of items i don't know about your items ;)

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery we can append new script tags like this after particular interval of time say 3000 ms.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      var my_awesome_script = document.createElement('script');    
      my_awesome_script.setAttribute('src','http://example.com/site.js');    
      document.head.appendChild(my_awesome_script);
      
    }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: how can I use this to load multiple scripts?

Comment: Either jQuery.each() or array "forEach" or "for" loop can be used to loop through all the scripts and inside the loop goes the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

The best option here is to use internal js, instead of external script files. Because external script files have higher importance and they will be loaded along with the page. So, if you want the JS to start after the HTML, CSS and Images have completely loaded, change the code into internal JS and use one of these methods:

```
window.onload = function ...
```

This allows you to call a function once the window has been completely loaded.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
// ....
});
```

This event listener allows you to call a JS function once the page is completely loaded and parsed. Try one of these